# How to return array from three joined tables Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables

```
- Patients 
- Medicines
- Services
- Patient_medicines
- Patients_services
```

I have left joined them and get the following results

```
firstname : Nassoro,
lastname : Hamisi
Medicines : Dou Cotexin
Services : See a Doctor

firstname : Nassoro,
lastname : Hamisi
Medicines : Dou Cotexin
Services : TEST UTI

firstname : Nassoro,
lastname : Hamisi
Medicines : Malaphin
Services : See A doctor

firstname : Nassoro,
lastname : Hamisi
Medicines : Malaphin
Services : TEST UTI
```

But I want to get array

```
firstname : Nassoro 
lastname : Hamisi
Medicines :{'Malaphon' , 'Duo Cotexin'}
Services : {'See a Doctor' , 'TEST UTI'}
```

I am using Laravel

Comment: I think you can use groupby clause with your leftjoin query

Comment: You have to write subquery for Services column

Answer (score 1):

you can encode your result to get output as mentioned

Store your Result in a variable and pass it to to encode method

```
json_encode($variable);
```

Hope it will work for you